# regex to match terms in multiple lines

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been using a positive and negative lookahead regex to match occurrences in a string, like:

```
/^(?=.*term1)(?=.*term2)(?!.*term3).*$/
```

Now I have a new requirement to match those strings across multiple lines. Seems like the `m` modifier will match those terms for each line, not exactly what i need.

Am I missing something? Is there another solution?

Comment: JS don't use dot-all. Change the dot to `[\S\s]` which matches newlines as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex to match across the lines in Javascript:

```
/^(?=[^]*term1)(?=[^]*term2)(?![^]*term3)[^]*$/
```

In JS, `[^]` matches any character including new line.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jA0nB6/1)

If not using JS or want to make this regex portable to other flavors then one can use:

```
/^(?=[\D\d]*term1)(?=[\D\d]*term2)(?![\D\d]*term3)[\D\d]*$/
```

Comment: `[^]` not too portable to other flavors.

Comment: Is there another alternative?

Comment: Yes, it is JS specific. `[\S\s]` or any other variant like `[\D\d]` works in other flavors as well.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the "^" and "$" From your regex, like

```
/(?=.*term1)(?=.*term2)(?!.*term3).*/
```

"^" denotes start of line and "$" denotes end of line, so this will only ever match one line.